# ¿Còmo funciona el metacaracter\?

Tags: javascript

¿Còmo funciona el metacaracter"'? Por ejemplo si hago esto:

`var a ='\';document.write(a);`

no funciona, pero si hago esto:

`var a ='\\';document.write(a);`

Si funciona.

He leìdo que "escapar"
¿Que es lo realmente significa?

Comment: La etiqueta de la pregunta (Android Studio es un IDE) no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta (sobre escapar caracteres en algún lenguaje, parece que Javascript. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para aclarar?

Answer (score 1):

No es tanto el carácter comilla simple (') sino el carácter barra (\).

El carácter barra se utiliza en muchos lenguajes de programación para indicarle al intérprete o compilador que el siguiente carácter tiene un significado especial. **A este caracter se le suele llamar carácter de escape.** Voy a asumir que el lenguaje en el que estás trabajando es JavaScript.

Por ejemplo si tienes la letra n:

```
n
```

el intérprete entiende que es, en efecto, la letra n.

Pero si le pones una barra delante:

```
\n
```

el intérprete entiende que te refieres a un salto de línea (\n).

Hay varios de estos caracteres especiales, como \t, \v, \r, etc. con diferentes usos y significados.

Entonces, ¿qué pasa si quieres escribir una cadena como esta?:

```js
console.log('ocho\nueve');
```

El intérprete va a entender lo siguiente:

```
ocho
ueve
```

Es decir, mete un salto de línea y la "n" ni si quiera la escribe. Esto lo hace porque va leyendo carácter a carácter y cuando llega a la barra, mira el siguiente carácter para ver si es un carácter especial. Como \n es especial,  sustituye esos dos caracteres por un salto de línea. Si el siguiente carácter no está en su lista de caracteres especiales, interpreta el siguiente carácter de forma literal.

En el caso anterior, si escribiésemos:

```js
console.log('ocho\\nueve');
```

El interprete llegaría a la primera barra, y miraría que hay después. Mira a ver si es \n, \r, o alguno de los caractereres especiales. Como no lo encuentra en la lista, sabe que lo que queremos es escribir literalmente el carácter barra. Por lo que lo que entiende es esto:

```
ocho\nueve
```

En tu caso, tienes esta variable:

```
var a = '\';
```

Y aquí tienes otro problema de escapado.

Por que, imagínate que quieres escribir una cadena que lleve una comilla simple. Por ejemplo:

```
It's raining.
```

Si escribes:

```js
console.log('It's raining.');
```

Vas a ver que falla. Esto es porque el intérprete entiende que la cadena empieza en la I y acaba en la t: 'It' y todo lo demás es para él basurilla que ha quedado a continuación de esa cadena. De hecho fíjate que se ha quedado en verde solo el It y el resto no, eso ya es una pista que nos puede dar el IDE.

¿Cómo se soluciona esto? Escapando la comilla simple:

```js
console.log('It\'s raining.');
```

Ese \' es un carácter especial que indica que es literalmente una comilla simple y no es una apertura/cierre de comillas simples para delimitar una cadena de caracteres.

Volviendo a tu caso:

```
var a = '\';
```

El intérprete llega a la barra y mira lo que hay en el siguiente carácter y se encuentra una comilla simple. Resulta que \' es el carácter especial que representa una comilla simple. Por lo que empieza una cadena de caracteres y el primer carácter que interpreta es una comilla simple. Pero después falta otra comilla simple para cerrar la cadena.

Pero si "escapas" el carácter como has hecho en tu ejemplo:

```
var a = '\\';
```

El intérprete llega a la primera barra, ve que después hay otra barra, por lo que entiende que quieres guardar literalmente el carácter barra. Por lo que solo guarda en la variable una barra. Así si ves el contenido de la variable:

```js
var a = '\\';
console.log(a);
```

Se ve que solo guarda una barra.

Si lo que quisiéramos es guardar una comilla simple habría que hacer esto:

```js
var a = '\'';
console.log(a);
```

Esto es, abro cadena ('), escribo comilla simple ('), cierro cadena (').

Más info:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp